# Dark mode gets turned off on refresh a page

Tags: javascript

my page not load darkmode when it refresh

```
const dayNight = document.querySelector(".day-night");
dayNight.addEventListener("click", () => {
    dayNight.querySelector("i").classList.toggle("fa-sun");
    dayNight.querySelector("i").classList.toggle("fa-moon");
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark");
});
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    if (document.body.classList.contains("dark")) {
        dayNight.querySelector("i").classList.add("fa-sun");
    } else {
        dayNight.querySelector("i").classList.add("fa-moon");
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/styles/variables.scss#L66)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to persist the data.

```
const dayNight = document.querySelector(".day-night");
dayNight.addEventListener("click", () => {
    dayNight.querySelector("i").classList.toggle("fa-sun");
    dayNight.querySelector("i").classList.toggle("fa-moon");
    const isDark = document.body.classList.toggle("dark");
    // Persist this locally
    localStorage.setItem("dark", isDark);
});
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const isDark = localStorage.getItem("dark");
    if (isDark === "true") {
        document.body.classList.add("dark");
        dayNight.querySelector("i").classList.add("fa-moon");
    } else {
        document.body.classList.remove("dark");
        dayNight.querySelector("i").classList.add("fa-sun");
    }
})
```

You can also checkout [@media prefers-color-scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) css media feature to detect it with respect to user's system preferences.

Comment: still not working sir,i try go live from vscode but when i refresh the page it will be start from day mode

Comment: I have added additional checks in the answer now. If it's exists further, kindly please include your full code / [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to debug further.